# Javascript stopwatch! The stopwatch starts at 1 hour

Tags: javascript, stopwatch

i have a question to my javascript stopwatch
When i start my stopwatch with the start button the stopwatch instantely shows one hour (01:00:00)
From there its counting normally.
Can someone help me and tell me a solution against the instant start at one hour?
I would appreciate a fast answer a lot
Thank you a lot

```
<div class="container">
      <h1 class="screen">
        <span id="hours">
          00
        </span>:<span id="minutes">
          00
        </span>:<span id="seconds">
          00
        </span>
      </h1>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button id="start">START CHARGE</button>
        <button id="stop">STOP CHARGE</button>
        <button id="reset">RESET TIMER</button>
      </div>
   </div>
<script>class State {
  constructor(startTimestamp, difference, suspended) {
    this.startTimestamp = startTimestamp;
    this.difference = difference;
    this.suspended = suspended;
  }
  static ready() {
    return new State(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
class Stopwatch {
  constructor(state) {
    this.state = state;
    this.requestAnimationId = null;
    this.handleClickStart = this.handleClickStart.bind(this);
    document
      .getElementById("start")
      .addEventListener("click", this.handleClickStart);
    this.handleClickStop = this.handleClickStop.bind(this);
    document
      .getElementById("stop")
      .addEventListener("click", this.handleClickStop);
    this.handleClickReset = this.handleClickReset.bind(this);
    document
      .getElementById("reset")
      .addEventListener("click", this.handleClickReset);
    this.tick = this.tick.bind(this);
    this.render();
  }

  static ready() {
    return new Stopwatch(State.ready());
  }

  setState(newState) {
    this.state = {...this.state,...newState };
    this.render();
  }

  tick() {
    this.setState({
      difference: new Date(new Date() - this.state.startTimestamp)
    });
    this.requestAnimationId = requestAnimationFrame(this.tick);
  }

  handleClickStart() {
    if (this.state.startTimestamp) {

      return;
    }
    this.setState({
      startTimestamp: new Date() - this.state.suspended,
      suspended: 0
    });
    this.requestAnimationId = requestAnimationFrame(this.tick);
  }

  handleClickStop() {
    cancelAnimationFrame(this.requestAnimationId);
    this.setState({
      startTimestamp: null,
      suspended: this.state.difference
    });
  }

  handleClickReset() {
    cancelAnimationFrame(this.requestAnimationId);
    this.setState(State.ready());
  }

  render() {
    const { difference } = this.state;
    const seconds = (difference ? Math.floor(difference.getSeconds()) : 0)
      .toString()
      .padStart(2, "0");
    const minutes = (difference ? Math.floor(difference.getMinutes()) : 0)
      .toString()
      .padStart(2, "0");
    const hours = (difference ? Math.floor(difference.getHours()) : 0)
      .toString()
      .padStart(2, "0");

    // Render screen
    document.getElementById("hours").textContent = hours;
    document.getElementById("minutes").textContent = minutes;
    document.getElementById("seconds").textContent = seconds;
  }
}

const STOPWATCH = Stopwatch.ready()</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem lies with the Date Type.
you set it To a specific time at UTC but you get your data with GMT differences.

you can use something along the lines of:

```
var nowUTC = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(), now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes(), now.getUTCSeconds());
```

worked for me once upon a time

Comment: When i change my new Date () functions with your defined variable the stopwatch doesnt work

Comment: Do i have to add sth else then ?

Comment: the quick fix will actually be in the render I belive. you ask for getHours which is a Date class method. instead use getUTCHours() and it should work just fine

Comment: Thank you a lot . It worked and you saved my day with a little help haha

Answer (score 0):

As above, the problem is with how you're using your date type because of the time zone attached.  Date isn't particularly suited to storing durations, so to get it to work I made the following changes

```
  tick() {
    this.setState({
      difference: new Date() - this.state.startTimestamp
    });
    this.requestAnimationId = requestAnimationFrame(this.tick);
  }
```

and

```
  render() {
    const { difference } = this.state;
    const seconds = (difference ? Math.floor(difference/(1000) % 60) : 0)
      .toString()
      .padStart(2, "0");
    const minutes = (difference ? Math.floor(difference/(60*1000) % 60) : 0)
      .toString()
      .padStart(2, "0");
    const hours = (difference ? Math.floor(difference/(3600*1000) % 60) : 0)
      .toString()
      .padStart(2, "0");

    // Render screen
    document.getElementById("hours").textContent = hours;
    document.getElementById("minutes").textContent = minutes;
    document.getElementById("seconds").textContent = seconds;
  }
```